# Calendar time zone DST issue Calendar on codename

Tags: codenameone

We used following code to get the time

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour            = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute          = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int amPmVal         = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
```

But when we change Timezone to New York in iPad it gives 1 hour less.

Can we handle this DST issue in codename one?

Answer (score 0):

You set the hour but didn't set the date so DST might not be in effect. Also make sure DST is correctly set in the iPad itself and not just the hour.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. Can I wrote code like this                                        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(now.getTimeZone().getID());
        now.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        Calendar zoneTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        zoneTime.setTime(now.getTime());
        

        int hour            = zoneTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute          = zoneTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int amPmVal         = zoneTime.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

Comment: The above code also not working in iPad Shai. Can I have code sample please to handle DST.

Comment: Don't change the timezone, leave it as the default. That might disrupt the default behavior.